# How to select average on yii2 elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2, average

```
/**
 * @param mixed $article_id
 * @return double
 */
public function getAvg($article_id)
{
    return ArticleRate::find()->where(['article_id' => $article_id])
         ->average('rate');
}
```

On example using for RDBMS.

Now I convert the source to ElasticSearch.
`yii\elasticsearch\ActiveQuery` does not have the method `average()`, so what can I use instead?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the [addAggregation()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-elasticsearch-query.html#addAggregation()-detail) method of `ActiveQuery`. The [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html) has more information on the types of aggregation you can use, including the use of averages.

Comment: I have find found that, but not work, please example with yii2 script thanks.

Comment: @ĐộcHành Well show us what you have tried, and tell us what didn't work then!